# How does mod_rewrite send parameters?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I make file with "page.php" name and wrote this code in it:

```
echo $_GET['product'];
```

and in ".htaccess" I wrote this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)$ page.php?product=$1 [L]
```

all of these files are in "apache" folder in my localhost.
The problem is for this url `http://localhost/apache/book` instead of "book" it echos "page.php" I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because your rule is looping twice,

1. first time for `/apache/book` URI
2. second time for `/page.php`

To avoid this situation you need conditions like this:

```
# skip this rule for valid files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# skip this rule for valid directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

So combining all this your `/apache/.htaccess` will look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apache/

# skip this rule for valid files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# skip this rule for valid directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page.php?product=$1 [L,QSA]
```